# CLion does not print exceptions, even though other console output is printed

Tags: clion

I have CLion installed with presumably default configuration. I think something is wrong with it, because I can't see exceptions. For example, this code:

```
int main(){ throw 5; }
```

Prints only `Process finished with exit code 0`

- Why doesn't it print the exception?
- Why does it print 0 instead of 1?

Here is an example showing how other console output is printed and CLion is running code:

For comparison:

```
int main(){try { throw 5; } catch(int x) { std::cout << x << '\n'; }}
```

This prints `5`.

**Note: this is not a duplicate of "not seeing any console output". I can see console output just fine. The only thing that is not showing is error messages.**

Comment: Run your executable outside of CLion, on the command-line. Does it give the output you expect?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart When I run it on command-line, it's not giving any output at all. I think that's a different issue. I'd be happy enough to just get the IDE output working though.

Comment: If the standalone executable doesn't produce any output, why do you expect to see anything different in your IDE?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart As I said in OP, I am seeing output in IDE. I gave the example of printing `5`, which indeed prints `5` when I run it in the IDE.